# Why does my Android custom KeyboardView overflow after setting new Keyboard?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am developing a keyboard for android. Now I want to change my keyboard from the letters to symbols then the user press the '**123**' Button. 
My Poblem is, that the keyboard overflows after calling `keyboardView.setKeyboard()`.

What I tried:
I logged the width of the keyboards. the normal width is 720, after setting the new keyboard, it is over 800. 
I also tried to call `keyboardView.invalidate()` and i`nvalidateAllKEeys()`. Both had no effect. 
I copiy-pasted the keyboard XML layout to exclude issues caused by the layout.

How cat I fix that?

Thank you for helping me.

[Normal keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAND0.jpg)

[keyboard after setting new keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NPHF.jpg)

Here my Input Service class

```
package com.luxaaa.keyboardtest.services;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MyInputMethodService extends InputMethodService implements 
KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {
private KeyboardView keyboardView;
private Keyboard keyboard, keyBoardSymbolic;
private boolean caps = false;

Vibrator vibrator;
VibrationEffect vEffect;

public MyInputMethodService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    LinearLayout layout =new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    View view =  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_bar, null);


    // Keyboards
    keyboard =new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_layout);
    keyBoardSymbolic =new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_layout);

    keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view, null);

    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyBoardSymbolic);
   keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);



    layout.addView(view);
    layout.addView(keyboardView);

    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    if(primaryCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
        keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(true);
    }

    // key feedback
    vibrator.vibrate(50);

    // set shift keys pressed if caps
   if(primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT) {
       List<Keyboard.Key> keys = keyboard.getKeys();
       List<Keyboard.Key> keysSymbolic = keyBoardSymbolic.getKeys();
       for(Keyboard.Key key : keys) {
           if(key.codes[0] == primaryCode) {
               key.pressed = !caps;
           }
       }
       for(Keyboard.Key key : keysSymbolic) {
           if(key.codes[0] == primaryCode) {
               key.pressed = !caps;
           }
       }
   }

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
    if (inputConnection != null) {
        switch (primaryCode) {
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
                CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                    inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1,0);
                } else  {
                    inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
            }
                break;

            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT :
                caps = !caps;
                keyboard.setShifted(caps);
                keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE :
                inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                break;

            case -10 :

                keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
                break;

                default:

                    char code = (char) primaryCode;
                    if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
                        code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                    }
                    inputConnection.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
                break;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {

}


@Override
public void swipeLeft() {

}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {

}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {

}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem,I tried to adjust the horizontalGap and the verticalGap to smaller value, and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] your answer and post code that shows how to _adjust the horizontalGap and the verticalGap to smaller value_ ?